# Rotate image arbitrary in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, pattern-matching

I trying to recognize some banknotes. I tried with a haar cascade algorithm in opencv but I can't get good results so I will try with template matching.

I think, first thing I should do is rotate the banknote so I always get it in horizontal mode. 
this is what I am trying to recognize contours:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('10_euros_test1.jpg')
print im.shape #check if the image is loaded correctly
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
contours, hierarchy =     cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(im,contours,-1,(255,255,0),-1)

cv2.imshow("window title", im)
cv2.waitKey()
```

this is my banknote images:

[image]

What should I do right now to rotate them? Any example of getRotationMatrix2d fucntion?, I don't know how to get angles from here.

I think, there is something wrong witht he background in the second photo, maybe it is because of the lines in the table...

[image]

Comment: this is unanswered. Have you found a solution to it?